Flutter packages : Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion XX cannot be smaller than version XX declared in library
I'm not able to build android apk I'm receiving the followings errors below on my flutter project despite using latest targetsdk and minsdk settings
any workaround ?
My flutter version :
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale
en-DZ)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
My JDK :
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.2+9-70)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.2+9-70, mixed mode, sharing)
settings.gradle
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.6.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "3.0.2" apply false

}

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.1-all.zip

gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m

app/build.gradle
   android {
    ndkVersion "27.1.12297006"
    compileSdkVersion 35
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 35
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir 'build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib'

            }

            ndk {
                // replace with 'FULL' if you need more info,
                // but note that it will increase the file size of your appbundle dramatically.
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
            }

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    namespace 'xx.xxx.xx'

}

pubspec.yaml
version: 1.3.3+80
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
    
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.8
  firebase_core: 3.4.1
  firebase_messaging: 15.1.1
  shared_preferences: 2.3.2

  intl: 0.19.0
  bloc: 8.1.4
  url_launcher: 6.3.0
  flutter_bloc: 8.1.6
  share_plus: 10.0.2
  dio: 5.7.0
  cached_network_image: 3.4.1
  card_swiper: 3.0.1
  shimmer: 3.0.0
  image_picker: 1.1.2
  photo_view: 0.15.0

  google_maps_flutter: 2.9.0
  intro_views_flutter: 3.2.0
  rxdart: 0.28.0
  font_awesome_flutter: 10.7.0
  flutter_rating_bar: 4.0.1
  qr_flutter: 4.1.0
  dotted_border: 2.1.0
  animations: 2.0.11

  flutter_svprogresshud: 1.0.1

  #flutter_svprogresshud:
   # git:
    #  url: https://github.com/Syaba999/flutter_svprogresshud

  webview_flutter: 4.9.0
  showcaseview: 3.0.0
  google_mobile_ads: 5.1.0

  video_player: 2.9.1
  path_provider: 2.1.4

  open_filex: 4.5.0
  geolocator: 13.0.1
  shared_value: ^3.0.0
  one_context: ^4.0.0
  toast: ^0.3.0
  flutter_widget_from_html: 0.15.2
  screen_protector: ^1.4.2

  flutter_feather_icons: ^2.0.0+1
  get: ^4.6.6

  connectivity_plus: 6.0.5

  new_version_plus: ^0.0.11
  rate_my_app: ^2.2.0

  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  upgrader: ^11.0.0
  #  sentry_flutter: ^7.16.1

  firebase_crashlytics: ^4.1.1
  firebase_performance: ^0.10.0+6
  firebase_app_check: ^0.3.1+1
  #ios
  firebase_analytics: ^11.3.1

  flutter_map: ^7.0.2
  latlong2: ^0.9.1

  qr_code_scanner: 1.0.1

  #qr_code_scanner:
   # git:
    #  url: https://github.com/samnbd/qr_code_scanner
     # ref: master
      #version: ^1.0.0

  #qr_code_scanner:
   # git:
    #  url: https://github.com/dola99/qr_code_scanner
     # ref: update

  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^26.2.8
  in_app_review: 2.0.9

  flutter_colorpicker: 1.1.0
  shorebird_code_push: ^1.1.4
  restart_app: ^1.3.2

  assistive_touch: 0.2.0
  pin_code_fields: 8.0.1

  location: ^7.0.0

  device_info_plus: 10.1.2

dependency_overrides:
  package_info_plus: 8.0.2
  # http: ^1.2.2
  web: ^1.0.0

Error logs :
    1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Unable to make progress running work. There are items queued for execution but none of them can be started

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':open_filex:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [androidx.fragment:fragment:1.7.1] /Users/g-besoin/.gradle/caches/8.10.1/transforms/6794493f0b6fdfd574744e6342ad8026/transformed/fragment-1.7.1/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.fragment" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0] /Users/g-besoin/.gradle/caches/8.10.1/transforms/9f900b64ef0ab40207bfa7eabcd4c437/transformed/jetified-play-services-location-21.2.0/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.location" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_svprogresshud:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > 20 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:
     
       1.  Dependency 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.7.1' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       2.  Dependency 'androidx.window:window:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       3.  Dependency 'androidx.window:window-java:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       4.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.1' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       5.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       6.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       7.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       8.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
       9.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      10.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      11.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.13.1' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      12.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      13.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      14.  Dependency 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 33, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      15.  Dependency 'androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.1' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 33, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      16.  Dependency 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 31, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      17.  Dependency 'androidx.tracing:tracing:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 33, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      18.  Dependency 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 33, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      19.  Dependency 'androidx.window.extensions.core:core:1.0.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 33, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).
     
      20.  Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :flutter_svprogresshud is currently compiled against android-28.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
           of at least 34, for example 35.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).


5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_svprogresshud:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [androidx.fragment:fragment:1.7.1] /Users/g-besoin/.gradle/caches/8.10.1/transforms/6794493f0b6fdfd574744e6342ad8026/transformed/fragment-1.7.1/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.fragment" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)


6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:
     
       1.  Dependency ':qr_code_scanner' requires core library desugaring to be enabled
           for :app.
     
           See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html for more
           details.

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':qr_code_scanner:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).


It seems like you have many dependencies issues. Lucky for you, the issues are pretty clear and how to resolve them is stated in the log you shared. I can suggest doing what is recommended (I.E. upgrading the API level, minSdkLevel and so forth). You might have to upgrade library versions to resolve some of these.

Unfortunately upgrading them manually one by one doesn't solve it either
I'm looking for stable version which doesn't request these changes

Worth to share your pubspec.yaml so we can understand what versions you are using.

All my packages are latest versions.
for now I think only workaround is to downgrade my flutter but not sure which one support API 19
also which gradle and jdk should I use

Share your flutter doctor output

Here I updated my question

@IshaqMoutanabiBenaissa
If you can't change the libraries to some other working ones. The best way to solve this is to fork these libraries and see if the version upgrade is working on those package examples. If yes then you can use your own forked version of those libraries in your project.

I was having the exact same issue. Let me describe how I resolved it. First of all, the recommended action of 'Update this project to use a newer compileSdk of at least 34, for example 35.' is not about your app, it recommends increasing compileSdk of google_mobile_ads.

In your app's build.gradle, revert compileSdk and targetSdk as follows:
compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion

Find the build.gradle of google_mobile_ads. It should be '~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_mobile_ads-5.1.0/android/build.gradle'. Change the compileSdk as 34 and also disable 'MissingClass' in lintOptions:


android {
compileSdk 34

...
lintOptions {
    ...
    disable 'MissingClass'
}
...

}

Run './gradlew clean build' and the build should be successful.

I tested the functionality with an Interstitial Ad on iOS and Android, it seems working. Let me know if it works for you. Here is the plugin versions from my settings.gradle for your reference:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.6.0' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "3.0.2" apply false
}

